# ValueError: Layer model expects 2 input(s), but it received 3 input tensors. Inputs received

Tags: python, tensorflow

1. python3.8
2. tensorflow2.4
3. ubuntu20.04

I am trying to build a image captioning custom dataset with tensorflow.

The error says

```
File "/keras_imagecaption/p3.py", line 429, in <module>
    tr.TrainModel()
  File "/keras_imagecaption/japa_p3.py", line 348, in TrainModel
    self.model.fit_generator(generator, epochs=self.epochs, steps_per_epoch=steps, verbose=1)
  File "/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 1847, in fit_generator
    return self.fit(
    ValueError: Layer model expects 2 input(s), but it received 3 input tensors. Inputs received: [<tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:0' shape=(None, None) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:1' shape=(None, None) dtype=int32>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:2' shape=(None, None) dtype=float32>]
```

```
    def DataGenerator(self):
        """
        ・model.fit_generatorに読み込ませるデータジェネレータを作成する。
        """
        while 1:
            for key, image_texts in self.train_texts_dict.items():
                image_feature = self.train_features_dict[key][0]
                in_img, in_seq, out_word = self.MakeInputOutput(image_texts, image_feature)
                #yield [[in_img, in_seq], out_word]
                yield [[in_img, in_seq], out_word]
    def TrainModel(self):
        """
        ・モデルを訓練する。
        """
        self.MakeTokenizer()
        self.GetVocabSize()
        self.GetMaxLength()
        self.MakeCaptioningModel()

        steps=len(self.train_texts_dict)
        for i in range(self.epochs):
            generator = self.DataGenerator()

            self.model.fit_generator(generator, epochs=self.epochs, steps_per_epoch=steps, verbose=1)
            print("fit")
            self.model.save('model_' + str(i) + '.h5')
        return None
```

Comment: This might not be the problem but in this Github issue (https://github.com/XifengGuo/CapsNet-Keras/issues/126), a similar error message was resolved. It might be possible to adapt the solution detailed in this response (https://github.com/XifengGuo/CapsNet-Keras/issues/126#issuecomment-1019544566) to your situation. In ```DataGenerator()```, try yielding like this instead: ```yield[(in_img, in_seq), out_word]```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I fixed it but I am getting the same error again.

Comment: (reference)
https://qiita.com/yutaoba/items/6eb0e12ba0d169a480df

import keras →import tensorflow.python.keras